# Copying and pasting into a new sheet based on a list that changes

Tags: vba, excel

I need help copying part of sheet and placing into a new sheet. However I only need the header and point names. This what I am currently working on, however it only copies over the header.

```
Dim num As Integer, counter As Integer, pCount As Integer
counter = 0
Dim rngPN As Range
Dim pName As String

'Header
Sheets("Input Raw Data").Select
Range("A1").Copy
Sheets("Point Names").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Point Names
pName = "Point_" & num & ":"
Set rngPN = Sheets("Point Names").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
pCount = Sheets("Input Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).row
For counter = 2 To pCount
    If Range("A" & counter).Value = pName Then
        Range("A" & counter & ":D" & counter).Copy (rngPN)
        Set rngPN = rngPN.Offest(1, 0)
    End If
Next counter
```

The list that I am working with varies in length based on data provided. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's `num`? Where do you define that?

Comment: Dim num As Integer

Comment: I mean, when the line `pName = "Point_" & num & ":"`, there is no value given to `num`.  Don't you need to add say `num = 1` somewhere before that line?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, I am new to VBA and coding in general
`num` is any integer, like I said, the list length changes so it could be `Point_4:` or `Point_44:`

Comment: How do you know what number it should be? Is it the amount of rows in column A (or some other column), amount of certain data, etc.?

Comment: The numbers increase from row 1 to row x.  The thing that changes is the number of said rows, by factors of 3, so there could be 3 rows, or there could be 39 rows, plus a header in cell `"A1"`.

Comment: Is the "header" the value in `A1`?  Just quickly try putting `num = 3` right before `pName = "Point_"...` and see if it copies a row (assuming your `... = pName` hits.  You're not getting any data, because `pName` won't ever be found, since you never set `num`.

Comment: That didn't work.  It only copied over the header which is in A1, yes.

Comment: You also need to add the worksheet before each use of `Range()`. Otherwise, it's going to look at whatever the ActiveSheet is. Which I think would be `Point Names`.  It's going to check each value in `Point Names`  sheet.  Step through this with `F8` to see where the loop isn't working and see if you can trouble shoot from there. Some sample data may help too, as your question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using a much simpler method, thank you for your help @BruceWayne

```
Sheets("Input Raw Data").Select
counter = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)), "P*")
counter = counter + 1 'Moves down one row because of header

'Paste to Point Names tab
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1:A" & counter).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Point Names").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```